# sort results elasticsearch with higher pagerank and lower URL

Tags: elasticsearch

In my index on elasticsearch I have site registration, where I have the fields (title, description, URL, pagerank and url_lenght)

the field (pagerank) I assign a value from 1 to 10 and a field (url_lenght) contains the size of the website's URL and I use these values ​​to display the most relevant results first.

When sort the results of my query I order as follows:

```
{
 "pagerank": {
 "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "url_length": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
```

In this way it displays the results with the decreasing (pagerank) EX. 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5 .... Along with the smallest field values ​​(url_length) in ascending order EX: 33, 47, 69, 81 ...

This way can give me the result of the query with the ordering below example.

result: 1
pagerank: 10
url_lenght: 70

result: 2
pagerank: 9
url_lenght: 55

result: 3
pagerank: 8
url_lenght: 45

result: 4
pagerank: 7
url_lenght: 50

result: 5
pagerank: 6
url_lenght: 30

result: 6
pagerank: 5
url_lenght: 28

result: 7
pagerank: 4
url_lenght: 25

result: 8
pagerank: 3
url_lenght: 20

However, the smaller the field (url_lenght) is more relevant to me but with the higher value of (pagerank). Therefore, there is some way for me to say that at the time of ordering, the result (2) that has the pagerank: 9 and the url_lenght; 55 is more relevant and must appear first than the result (1) that has the pagerank: 10 and
url_lenght: 70

If I sort first by the field (url_lenght) and then by the field (pagerank) it will not solve my problem because it will display the results first with lower values ​​of the field (url_lenght) but will also display the lowest (pagerank) first.

```
{
            "url_length": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        },

 {
            "pagerank": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
```

EX:

result: 1
pagerank: 3
url_lenght: 20

result: 2
pagerank: 4
url_lenght: 25

result: 3
pagerank: 5
url_lenght: 28

result: 4
pagerank: 6
url_lenght: 30

result: 5
pagerank: 8
url_lenght: 45

result: 6
pagerank: 7
url_lenght: 50

result: 7
pagerank: 9
url_lenght: 55

result: 8
pagerank: 10
url_lenght: 70

Comment: {pagerank: 10 url_lenght: 70},{pagerank: 9 url_lenght: 55}  How to determine rank 9 not rank 8 is more relevant

Comment: @jaspreet chahal  through the (url_leght) = 55 which is less than (url_leght) = 70. I need a sort script to sort how I want it in elasticsearch. You know how to do? because I want to pay somebody to do this for me

Comment: For all the 8 pagerank , what is the final order after sort, can you add that in question

Comment: @jaspreet chahal I need to be showing in the results the biggest pageranks, but with the smallest url_lenght. do you have email? because I need to hire someone to do this for me

Comment: jaspreet chahal if the (url_lenght) of the bottom result is less than the (url_lenght) of the result from above, he takes the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In elastic search it is not possible to loop through all documents and then rearrange them 
according to some logic.

There is a [rank feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-rank-feature-query.html) which might help to resolve your query.

> Boosts the relevance score of documents based on the numeric value of
>   a rank_feature or rank_features field.
>
> The rank_feature query is typically used in the should clause of a
>   bool query so its relevance scores are added to other scores from the
>   bool query.

I have indexed documents with below mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "pagerank": {
        "type": "rank_feature"
      },
      "url_length": {
        "type": "rank_feature",
        "positive_score_impact": false -->  a long URL correlates negatively to relevance
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "rank_feature": {
            "field": "pagerank"
          }
        },
        {
          "rank_feature": {
            "field": "url_length",
            "boost": 0.5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index76",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "NxvgTnIB8mx5yKbJS7Gv",
        "_score" : 0.7809353,
        "_source" : {
          "pagerank" : 9,
          "url_length" : 55
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index76",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "NhvgTnIB8mx5yKbJRbHL",
        "_score" : 0.77814615,
        "_source" : {
          "pagerank" : 10,
          "url_length" : 70
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index76",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "OBvgTnIB8mx5yKbJVLFC",
        "_score" : 0.77697754,
        "_source" : {
          "pagerank" : 8,
          "url_length" : 45
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index76",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "OhvgTnIB8mx5yKbJa7Gw",
        "_score" : 0.75560117,
        "_source" : {
          "pagerank" : 6,
          "url_length" : 30
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index76",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ORvgTnIB8mx5yKbJXbFp",
        "_score" : 0.7303854,
        "_source" : {
          "pagerank" : 7,
          "url_length" : 50
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index76",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "OxvgTnIB8mx5yKbJe7H6",
        "_score" : 0.71875805,
        "_source" : {
          "pagerank" : 5,
          "url_length" : 28
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index76",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "PBvgTnIB8mx5yKbJgrEC",
        "_score" : 0.6789241,
        "_source" : {
          "pagerank" : 4,
          "url_length" : 25
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

It provides different functions to calculate relevance based on different mathematical formulas

**1. saturation**

> S / (S + pivot)

**2. log**

> log(scaling_factor + S)

**3. sigmoid**

> S^exp^ / (S^exp^ + pivot^exp^)

You need to calculate by what factor you want a field to contribute to score